# Field of Extremal - Euler-Lagrange

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I need to construct a field of extremals for the functional 
$J=\int_1^2 t^2 \dot{x}^2 + 2x^2 dt$. With the initial conditions $x(1)=0$ and $x(2)=7$.
I know the first step is to use Euler-Lagrange but I'm struggling to compute 
$\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}-\frac{d}{d t}(\frac{\delta f}{\delta \dot{x}})=0$. 
How do i solve $4x-\frac{d}{d t}(2t^2\dot{x})=0$?

Comment: Try to find solutions of the E-L equation as monomials $x=t^n$.